# asp.net literal doesnt display <br><hr>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using literal control to show a text which is in html format.it doesn't display br,hr tags as result the empty space line disappears.can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: You should post your code when asking a question like this, so we know _exactly_ what you are doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asp:Literal control has a `Mode` property, try setting it to [PassThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) e.g.

```
<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" Text="This<hr />Works" runat="server" />
```

This will output:

[image]

Which seems to be what you're after...

**Edit** following OPs comment: Another example that does exactly what he wants:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" Text="<p>para 1</p><br/><p>para2 </p>"/>
```

Outputs as:

[image]

I'm guessing you have some CSS or other styling that is messing around with your output. I recommend testing this on a clean project to see that it works as expected...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please post the code you used (inside your original question)...

Comment: For eg consider this html code <p>para 1</p><br/><p>para2 </p>.It should display as para1 with an empty space line followed by para2 however it displays as para 1 is followed by para 2 with no empty space line.

Comment: Sounds like you have some problems in your specific solution... Maybe a CSS file that is causing problems? I updated my answer to show you that your example works fine too...

Comment: @Blachasama Yes CSS was causing problems.@ALLThanks for your valuable thoughts

Comment: @sai Is there a reason you removed this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
```

*Definitions from MSDN:*

**PassThrough**: The contents of the control are not modified.

**Encode**: The contents of the control are converted to an HTML-encoded string.

**Transform:** Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

```
Transform Mode:
<br />
<asp:Literal ID="literal1" Mode="Transform" Text="<b>This is Transform </b>" 
runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
Pass Through Mode:
<br />
<asp:Literal ID="literal2" Mode="PassThrough" Text="<b><u>This is Pass Through</b></u>" runat="server" />
<br />

<br />
Encode Mode:
<br />
<asp:Literal ID="literal3" Mode="Encode" Text="<b>This is Encode </b>" 
runat="server" />
</div>
</asp:Content>

<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000099" />
</asp:Content>
```